# How to calculate weighted average in window join?

Tags: kdb

Is there a way to calculate weighted average in a window join (wj)
Since we can use `min, max, avg` there should be a way to use `wavg` too?

```
wj[w; `sym`time; tbl; (data; (wavg; `quantity; `price))]
```

This just gives me a list of values preceded by wavg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the 2 step workaround.

```
update price: quantity wavg' price from wj[w; `sym`time; tbl; (data; (::; `price); (::; `quantity))];
```

Answer (score 1):

I remember encountering a similar issue before. Try this:

```
wj[w; `sym`time; tbl; (data; (wavg[;]; `quantity; `price))]
```

Comment: nuh, doesn't work. gives the same list with `wavg[;]` preceding